# In Appium, How to Scroll and validate the required set of elements are available in the Android screen using a Java method?

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

In my Android app, I need to scroll down the screen and validate whether the required elements(each individual element) are available or not. How do I achieve this with a Java method?

Comment: you can achieve scrolling by using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233444/swipe-funtion-in-andriod-for-java-client-5-0-3-is-not-working/49233835#49233835 and after every scrolling you have validate your expected value

Comment: Thanks. Following your approach throws an error as "press
(io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption)
in TouchAction cannot be applied"

Comment: The solution was for java-client 5.x, i'm not sure which java-client version are you using!

Comment: How do i check the java-client version that am using?

Comment: You can check from `external library` folder or `pom.xml` file

Comment: you can try this, the solution for `java-client 6.x` http://ezyautomation.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-perform-vertical-and-horizontal.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing this and Appreciate your help. While calling the swipeVertical/SwipeHorizontal instead of giving the values and duration, is there a way where I scroll down the screen until I find a specific element?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code for scrolling up and down using JAVA.

`driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"**Text you want to Find**\"));");`

Thanks.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you -- Nauman Malik

Answer (score 0):

The good way here is to use native UIAutomator find strategy:

```
public void isElementPresent(String resourceId) {
    return androidDriver.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()
       .scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId("<your app package name>:id/" + resourceId + "\"))")
       .size() > 0; 
}
```

It will scroll down & up the view to find an element by provided `resourceId` and return `true` if element present.

Answer (score 0):

***Use the following code to scroll up using java :***

```
public void swipeUp(AppiumDriver<?> appiumDriver, MobileElement fromPosition, MobileElement toPosition) {
        Dimension size = fromPosition.getSize();
        Dimension size1 = toPosition.getSize();
        TouchAction swipe = new TouchAction(appiumDriver)
                .press(ElementOption.element(fromPosition, size.width / 2, size.height - 20))
                .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(4)))
                .moveTo(ElementOption.element(toPosition, size1.width / 2, size1.height / 2 + 30)).release();
        swipe.perform();
        logger.info("Swipe Success");
    }
```